# IDE: E(fx)clipse not working

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx-2

I installed e(fx)clipse plugin to Eclipse Neon, after I restart the IDE, i'm getting a prompt "Java Initialize Error". And also some of the eclipse features are not working.

**In the Log file, it shows**

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2016-07-18 10:21:44.162
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.core.runtime.SubMonitor.done(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor;)V
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.PatternSearchJob.execute(PatternSearchJob.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.performConcurrentJob(JobManager.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.BasicSearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(BasicSearchEngine.java:1816)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchEngine.searchAllTypeNames(SearchEngine.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.initializeAfterLoad(JavaCore.java:4270)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.InitializeAfterLoadJob$RealJob.run(InitializeAfterLoadJob.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message. If there is edit your question to add the details from the .log.

Answer (score 0):

You need set Java Home Path.

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs ->

**Click** Add -> **Select** Standard VM -> **Click** Next -> **Select** Directory ->

**Goto** C Drive Program Files -> Expand Java -> **Select** jdk1.8.0_74 -> **Click** OK -> **Click** Finish ->

**Select** jdk1.8.0_74 (default) -> **Click** Apply and ok